# Import Class from a dll (64bits

Tags: c++, class, 64-bit, dllimport, vcl

We are trying to convert our 32-bit application to 64-bit with Embarcadero C++Builder 10.4 Sydney.

We observe that when we create an instance of a class defined in a DLL with `new`, there is an Access Violation error when this class inherits from a VCL class.

The class is defined like this in the DLL:

```cpp
#ifdef __BUILD_COMPONENTS__
  #define EXP_COMPONENT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define EXP_COMPONENT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class EXP_COMPONENT MyClass : public TObject{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    __fastcall MyClass();
};
```

There is no problem if we use a function that creates the instance of the class directly in the DLL:

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) MyClass* __stdcall initialise_MyClass()
{
    MyClass * mc;
    mc = new MyClass();
    return mc;
}
```

And there is also no problem using `new` directly in a 32-bit application:

```cpp
MyClass *mc;
mc = initialise_MyClass(); // works good in 32/64-bit
mc = new  MyClass();       //works good in 32-bit
                           //Access Violation error in 64-bit
```

Is there something in particular to do in a 64-bit application when we want to import a class from a DLL?

Comment: You can't mix 32 and 64 bit binaries. Rebuild all dependencies for 64 bit to use with 64 bit.

Comment: Are you actually importing a 64 bit dll into a 64 bit process? Or a 32 bit dll into a 64 bit process. That's not clear from your question.

Comment: fyi `__fastcall` is ignored on _"...The `__fastcall` keyword is accepted and ignored by the compilers that target ARM and __x64 architectures__;..."_ - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fastcall?view=msvc-160

Comment: Thanks for your answers... I am actually importing a 64 bit dll into a 64 bit process.. I don't mix 32bit and 64 bit. It works good if I use a package instead of a dll but I don't understand why...

Comment: @jmr Because a Package has built-in support for the VCL/RTL, especially when used across the DLL boundary.  A plain DLL does not.  If you want to directly use a VCL-based class over the DLL boundary, a Package is the correct way to handle it, in both 32bit and 64bit.